# OrientDB - HTTP API with JSON Param for content 'merge'

Tags: orientdb

I am using the http API (v2.2.9 CE) to try and insert / update using JSON payloads

```
commandJSON["command"] = " update Worker merge :workerJSON where userName = :userName"

commandJSON["parameters"] = {"workerJSON": worker, "userName": userName}
```

an example 'worker' payload I am using to update the city location only is:

```
{
    "@class": "Worker",
    "city": "Cornwell"
}
```

(note: username passed is fine)

> "Error parsing query:\\u000a update Worker merge :workerJSON where
>   userName = :userName\\

I can run this using straight SQL in the studio but not via the REST api.  There is some issue it would seem with the JSON payload.

I am using python, and the requests package FYI to POST.

Any ideas?  Any suggestions on debugging serverside?

Comment: Hi, to reproduce your problem, are you using http://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html#post---command ?

Comment: Yes I am using the 'command' command.  Works with my GETs ok, returning and mapping scalar string param into the query.   Seems to be when JSON is needed as the content input I cant get it to work..... this even fails "update Worker merge {'city','cotswalds'} where userName = :userName" with a 400 when I embed it in the string?  Thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: If you use ```update Worker merge {'city','cotswalds'} ```it works,the problem appears in the param userName. it is correct ? if yes, you could open an issue on github, please ?